# detect DOM changes once document.ready() is fired

Tags: jquery, class, click, document-ready

I have this function inside a `$(document).ready`

```
$('.roundabout-in-focus').click(function(){
    $(this).css({position:'absolute',height:'300px',width:'400px',left:'120px',top:'-20px'});
});
```

Which works fine,

The problem is that the element that has `'.roundabout-in-focus'` class changes because of the plugin when the user clicks to another element.

let say, on document ready

```
<ul>
<li class="roundabout-in-focus">me first</li>
<li>me next</li>
</ul>
```

if user clicks to the next `<li>`

```
<ul>
<li>me first</li>
<li class="roundabout-in-focus">me next</li>
</ul>
```

but the click function I wrote at the beginning always applies to the same element, the one that had the class in the first place.

How can I update which element has the class?

Comment: does the class get removed from the original `<li>` ?

Comment: Yes, it does. I don't know why is still applying same item :S

Comment: using firebug, what does the code look like after you click the first `<li>`?

Comment: very similar to the code i posted in the question

Comment: Maybe you could post the exact code. Because i very much doubt firebug would show `<li class=".roundabout-in-focus">` as it's not marked up correctly.

Comment: well that's a typo error of mine here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("ul").delegate("li.roundabout-in-focus", "click", function() {
   $(this).css({position:'absolute',height:'300px',width:'400px',left:'120px',top:'-20px'});
});
```

or just

```
$('.roundabout-in-focus').live("click", function(){
    $(this).css({position:'absolute',height:'300px',width:'400px',left:'120px',top:'-20px'});
});
```

sorry I haven't tested either.. but they *should* work